# Create/update Amazon Athena tables from Amazon S3 bucket files

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have uploaded the MySQL csv file / MYSQL zip file of all tables in Amazon S3 bucket. Now I want to link the Amazon Athena with S3 bucket file. But when I write the schema for different tables is showing the same result for the select query of each table. I have search a lot but not able to understand the exact /correct way to do this.

I want to create/update different table schema in Athena with the help of one csv /sql zip file from S3 bucket.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon Athena will look in a defined **directory** for data. All data files within that directory will be treated as containing data for a given table.

You use a `CREATE TABLE` command to both define the schema and direct Athena to the directory, eg:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1 (
  f1 string,
  s2 string
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "escapeChar" = "\\") 
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/data-directory/'
```

You will need to run a `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` command for each table, and the data for each table should be in a separate directory. The CSV files can be in ZIP format (which makes it faster and cheaper to query).

As an alternative to writing these table definitions yourself, you can [create a crawler in AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html#crawler-configure-changes-console). Point the crawler to the data directory, supply a name and the crawler will examine the data files and create a table definition that matches the files.

Comment: Hi John,
Thanks for the fast reply.
I have more than 100 tables in my database, is this solution suitable for this, or do you have any other solution?

Comment: I'd need to understand your business requirements to answer that question. Amazon Athena is great for querying large amounts of data stored in an Amazon S3 datalake. It's not a traditional database since it can't do updates/inserts, so it is best used like a data warehouse where queries are run across lots of data. If you are running queries continuously throughout the day, it would be cheaper + better to use Amazon Redshift. Athena is better for data that is not often queried (since you only pay for queries).

Comment: Hi John, 
I want to connect the Amazon Athena to the tableau as a data source and I am uploading the database file in SQL zip format to the s3 bucket and trying to fetch the data in the Athena.
As you told to upload separate csv for each table in a separate folder, this is very tedious job. Can you suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: One option is to use the [AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html), which can [Use Amazon S3 as a Target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html). It can create Parquet files for each table, which is even more efficient for Amazon Athena.